# метод onUpgrade

Tags: java, android, sql

Здравствуйте, суть такова, в базе данных есть 3 таблицы, одна из этих таблиц называется `tags,` в которую записи добавляет сам пользователь приложения, так вот если я обновляю базу данных, соответственно версию БД меняю, код настроен так, если версия БД не совпадает со старой, то старая удаляется и новая записывается, но мне нужно вытащить таблицу `tags` и перекинуть ее в новую БД. Как это сделать?

Код таков:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
    initialize();
}

public void open() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

/**
 * Initializes database. Creates database if doesn't exist.
 */
public void initialize() {
    if (databaseExists()) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        int dbVersion = prefs.getInt("SP_KEY_DB_VER", 1);
        if (DB_VERSION != dbVersion) {
            File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
            if (!dbFile.delete()) {
                Log.w("TAG", "Unable to update database");
            }
        }
    }
    if (!databaseExists()) {
        createDatabase();
    }
}

private boolean databaseExists() {
    File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void createDatabase() {
    String parentPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent();
    String path = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

    File file = new File(parentPath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.mkdir()) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Unable to create database directory");
            return;
        }
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        os = new FileOutputStream(path);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        os.flush();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("SP_KEY_DB_VER", DB_VERSION);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                      int newVersion) {

}
```

Comment: а где ваша реализация метода onUpgrade, вобще если вы хотети сделать апгрейд базы кроме одной таблици, то вам нужно делать запрос на пересоздание таблиц, кроме той которая вам нужна. Что касаеться перекинуть - то просто сохраняете данные из нужной таблици, после чего вызываете onUpgrade и уже в новозоданную базу добавляете сохраненные данные, возможно я примитивно понял вашу задачу!

Comment: @KirillStoianov вот этот момент я и хотел бы узнать как это сделать, сохранить данные и перекинуть в новую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

Создать таблицы в виде отдельных классов так:

**UserTable.java**

```
public class UserTable {

    // Database table
    public static final String TABLE_USER = "table_user";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USER_TOKEN = "user_token";

    // Database creation SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table "
                    + TABLE_USER
                    + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_USER_TOKEN + " text "
                    + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
                                 int newVersion) {
        Log.w(UserTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

**OptionsTable.java**

```
public class OptionsTable {

    // Database table
    public static final String TABLE_OPTIONS = "table_options";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_DB_VERSION = "db_version";



    // Database creation SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table "
                    + TABLE_OPTIONS
                    + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_DB_VERSION + " text "
                    + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
                                 int newVersion) {
        Log.w(PacketTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_OPTIONS);
        onCreate(database);
    }

}
```

После чего создаете свой хелпер и в нем вы можете в методе  `onCreate()`
создавать все нужные таблицы а в методе `onUpgrade` указать только те таблицы которые должны быть обновлены, а те которые должны остаться нетронутыми - просто не прописывать в этом методе:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myApp.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        OptionsTable.onCreate(db);
        UserTable.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        UserTable.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

В этом примере будет создано две таблицы, но обновлению поддается только одна таблица - `UserTable`, `OptionsTable` - останется нетронутой.

---

В случае если у вас уже существует база данных, то вам нужны методы для того что  бы взять все объекты которые не должны быть затронуты апгрейдом а также метод для вставки этих объектов обратно. Получаеться взяли все объекты(сохранили например в `ArrayList`) после чего сделал `upgrade` ну и в уже обновленную базу данных вставляешь обратно данные из `ArrayList`.
Надуюсь тебе это поможет.

Comment: Мой тебе совет - подумай над архитектурой приложения, поскольку версию строения базы данных может задавать только программист Когда-то я разрабатывал приложение для сохранения списков фильмов/книг и прочего, тоже тэги и прочее было, поэтому могу поделиться опытом, если есть необходимость

Comment: @A.Ovsyannikov ???